# How does C++ determine this should be a string_view?

Tags: c++, local, auto, type-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    std::optional<std::string_view> opt { "abc" };
    std::cout << opt.value();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and when run outputs "abc" to the console. Why does it compile? The first line of code in main should be:

```
std::optional<std::string_view> { std::string_view { "abc" } };
```

How does the compiler know to make a call to the string_view constructor with the literal? This seems like it is doing more than just type deduction which I have seen before. Here it seems like the compiler is adding code to my source, i.e. a call to a constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does the compiler know to make a call to the string_view constructor with the literal?

`std::optional` has a constructor with the form of

```
template < class U = T >
constexpr optional( U&& value );
```

This is used to directly initialize the underlying object only if `T` can be constructed from `U`, which it can in this case using `std::string_view`'s

```
constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s);
```

constructor.

> This seems like it is doing more than just type deduction which I have seen before

You told the compiler you have a `std::optional<std::string_view>`, so it doesn't need to determine what type of optional you have.  It does determine what `U` would be in the constructor, and sees that is a type which can be used to construct a `std::string_view` with, and so it calls the constructor to do just that since it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your clear answer. From my example, it seems that I'm not just initialising one object though yet I only have one pair of braces. I'm initialising the optional and the underlying string_view. Does the initialisation syntax initialise as many objects deep as it needs?

Comment: @user2674487 You initializing the optional, and it is the optional that is forwarding on the initializer to the wrapped object to do its initialization.